# Disable all LinearLayout widgets at once

Tags: android

I put 6 EditTexts into one LinearLayout. Is there a way to disable all six EditTexts at once? I use java

Comment: Yes: disable the container View. All the children will inherit the disabled state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may help you :

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
for ( int i = 0; i < linearLayout .getCount();  i++ ){
   EditText editTexts = myLayout.getChildAt(i);
   editTexts.setEnabled(false); 
}
```

if you have another view in your layout, you can use `View` instead of `EditText`:

```
 View view = myLayout.getChildAt(i);
 view.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Shouldn't you check the  type of the child? if the LinearLayout have other types as well it can crush the app. I would suggest add something like `if (myLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof EditText) { do something}`